# Showing that a root $x_0$ of a polynomial is bounded by $|x_0|<(n+1)\cdot c_{\rm max}/c_1$

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics, roots

I have doubts about the following problem (Problem 3.21 from Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation"):

> Let $c_1 x^n + c_2 x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n x + c_{n+1}$ be a polynomial with a root at $x=x_0$. Let $c_{\rm max}$ be the largest absolute value of a $c_i$. Show that
>
> $$|x_0|<(n+1)\dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{c_1}.$$

Here is how I was able to approach it (I'm unsure that it's correct):

Making the polynomial equal zero (in this case, $x=x_0$):

$$c_1 x_0^n + c_2 x_0^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n x_0 + c_{n+1} = 0$$

Rearranging the terms:

$$c_1 x_0^n = -(c_2 x_0^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n x_0 + c_{n+1})$$

Taking the absolute value of both sides:

$$|c_1 x_0^n| = |c_2 x_0^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n x_0 + c_{n+1}|$$

Applying triangle inequality:

$$|c_1 x_0^n| \leq |c_2 x_0^{n-1}| + \cdots + |c_n x_0| + |c_{n+1}|$$

The inequality above still holds if we substitute $c_{max}$ for all coefficients:

$$|c_1 x_0^n| \leq |c_{max}| ( 1 + |x_0| + \cdots + |x_0^{n-1}| )$$

The inequality also holds if we substitute $n x_0^{n-1}$ for $1 + |x_0| + \cdots + |x_0^{n-1}|$ (because this sum has $n$ terms and $x_0^{n-1}$ is the largest one if $x_0>1$):

$$|c_1 x_0^n| \leq |c_{\rm max}| n |x_0^{n-1}|$$

$$|x_0| \leq n \dfrac{|c_{\rm max}|}{|c_1|}$$

From the above result, it is true that:

$$|x_0| < (n+1) \dfrac{|c_{\rm max}|}{|c_1|}$$

The above result is very close to the desired result, except that it should be $|x_0|<(n+1)\dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{c_1}$ (without the absolute bars).

Is this approach correct?

---

***Edit***: As pointed out in the comments, I also have to consider the case where $x_0\leq 1$.

If $x_0\leq 1$ then $\max(1, |x_0|,\cdots,|x_0|^{n-1}) = 1$, so $|c_1x_0^n|\leq |c_{\rm max}|n$, and $|x_0|\leq \left(n\dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{|c_1|}\right)^{1/n}$.

Since $c_{\rm max}\geq c_1$:

$|x_0| \leq \left(n\dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{|c_1|}\right)^{1/n}\leq n\dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{|c_1|} \leq (n+1) \dfrac{c_{\rm max}}{|c_1|}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $x^{n-1}$ is only the largest term if $x>1$

Comment: @Ethan: I added this observation to the post.

Comment: ...Good, but you are supposed to treat also the case $x\leqslant1$, not simply mention that you assume $x\gt1$ (and this case $x\leqslant1$ is not difficult but is not done at present).

Comment: @Did: I added an attempt for the case where $x_0\leq 1$.

Comment: @anonymous Please do not use `\dfrac`, or other commands giving vertically verbose expressions, in question titles -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @favq in the third edition of Sipser, the question has |$c_1$|, not $c_1$, so there is no error in the book.

Answer (score 4):

Sipser's $c_{max}$ is by definition the absolute value.  He forgot to mention that $c_1$ should be positive.  Otherwise the inequality does not make sense.

Comment: Seems a comment, more than an answer.

Comment: OP presented a solution and was wondering about the difference between their solution (with absolute values) and the expected answer (without absolute values). I pointed out that in fact the answer without the absolute values is incorrect.

Comment: the current (third) edition of the book _has_ $|c_1|$, _not_ $c_1$, so either the original asker was using an older version of the book that had an error, or the asker misquoted the book.

Answer (score 0):

consider the polynomial -x^2 + 2*x - 1 . It has roots 1 and 1 .
Now here Xo = 1 , Cmax = 2 and C1= -1 ;

So the inequality doesn't hold true here.

Comment: As has been pointed out, $c_1$ must be assumed to be strictly positive for the inequality to make sense

Answer (score 0):

The question asker is either using an older edition of Sipser's book or is misquoting it. In the third edition, the inequality is

$$
|x_0| < (n+1) \frac{c_\rm{max}}{|c_1|}
$$

where "$c_\rm{max}$ is the largest absolute value of a $c_i$". Hence, there is no error.